# How to set identity function in SQL Server for certain rows?

Tags: sql-server, database, identity

Hei, I have `table1` (with 550K entries) which has more columns, and a primary key `id`. I want to migrate the data from `table1` to `table2`, but with the same id (id in table1 is not consecutive, eg: 1, 2, 3, 6, 7...) and I want the same id in table2 for that rows. Is there a possibility to copy the 550k entries from table1 to table2 (with the same id) and then to make the id (which should be a primary key in table2) to start from 600K (for the new entries added in the future)? Like in table2 to be: entry1, entry2, ...entry 550k and the entries that will be added in future to start from 600k.

I tried to create table2 without primary key and create after a new column which is primary key and drop the `id` and renamed the newly created into `id`. But I don't know how can I change that identity to keep the old ones with their `id` and add the next added entries from a certain `id`